# Weird white vertical lines on my hair render using Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, hair

I'm having a problem when rendering hair using Eevee. I find that when I change the value of Specular to 0, it will disappear. However, this will remove the shine effect that I need.

In this image below, you can see my GlossDir render shows that the light reflection is weird.

[image: Weird vertical boxes on top of the hair.]

[image]

[image]

However, when checking different angles it disappears.

I tried turning off my lights, HDRI, and changing materials but the vertical over-exposed / boxed lines always show in my renders.

--EDIT--

Here are other image examples:

[image]
[image]

--EDIT--

Here is my Hair Material. It is pretty simple, I tried changing or making new material but it always does the same white vertical lines.

[image]

Comment: When you're asking a question regarding material issues, it's helpful if you at least post one screenshot of your material graph.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a problem with the material, not the hair.

Comment: I uploaded an image regarding the material. I tried changing or creating new material but it always does the same vertical white lines.